# Conexión entre segues en Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift

hace unos días no sabía como hacer una implementación para un Tab Bar Controller ya que el método `prepare` requería una implementación que ya está conseguida. Ahora el problema que tengo es que necesito implementar una funcionalidad y es que guarde los cambios que haga en cualquiera de las vistas del Tab Bar Controller. Como la otra vez, os dejo el proyecto en [GitHub](https://github.com/anonimous231/TabBarController.git) a ver si me podéis ayudar ya que no consigo hacer que se guarden los cambios por más que lo intento.

Este es el método `prepare` que he estado usando hasta ahora para guardar y que no funciona...

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    // Comprueba si el botón pulsado es exactamente el botón de guardar
    guard let button = sender as? UIBarButtonItem, button === saveButton else {
        os_log("El botón de guardar no se ha pulsado, cancelando", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return
    }

    let name = nameTextField.text ?? "" // Si no hay nada en el text field, asigno una cadena vacía
    let photo = photoImageView.image
    let rating = ratingControl.rating

    meal = Meal(name: name, photo: photo, rating: rating)

}
```

Espero que me podáis ayudar en esto ya que necesito hacer la entrega del proyecto.

Un saludo y muuuuuchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Lo que necesitas es pasar la información de la clase 'Meal' a la vista anterior?

Comment: Exacto, lo que necesito es que cuando haga algún cambio en alguna de las vistas del TabBarController, al dar en el botón de guardar, actualice la información de la comida en la vista principal de las comidas.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a esta Web, te podrá orientar en lo que necesitas. Si tienes dudas pregunta. La web es https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-view-controllers-swift-how-to/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola para obtener el valor de tu arreglo de Meals, te recomiendo para rapido y facil hacer una clase con las variables static que necesites, para empezar necesitarias el arreglo de Meals static y te recomiendo un valor id o index para que sepas en que posicion vas a ir actualizando o reemplazando.

```
class ClaseStaticGuardar {

static var meals = [Meal]()

static var nuevoMeal: Meal?
}
```

En tu clase Meal agrega una variable que se llame index o id o algo a si, algo que identifique cada uno de los item que vas a tener, a si al modificar alguno sabrás cual exactamente cambiar del array.

```
 var name: String
var photo: UIImage? // Es un optional porque lo mismo la comida no tiene foto asignada
var rating: Int
var index: Int
```

Entonces en tu clase MealTableViewController por ejemplo al guardar los elementos o en cualquier otra clase vas a llamar al arreglo de meals de esta manera:

ClaseStaticGuardar.meals

```
import UIKit
import os.log

class MealTableViewController: UITableViewController {

// MARK: Properties
//static var meals = [Meal]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Use the edit button item provided by the table view controller.
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem

    if let savedMeals = loadMeals() {
        ClaseStaticGuardar.meals += savedMeals
    }
    else {
        // Load the sample data.
        loadSampleMeals()
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
     print("viewWillAppear >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    tableView.reloadData()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // Tenemos sólo una sección, así que devolvemos 1
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ClaseStaticGuardar.meals.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Identificador que hemos elegido antes. Como iOS reutiliza las celdas para mejorar el rendimiento, es necesario indicar un identificador
    let cellIdentifier = "MealTableViewCell"

    // Hay que probar con el guard porque estamos haciendo un casting de un optional
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MealTableViewCell  else {
        fatalError("La celda no es del tipo MealTableViewCell.")
    }

    // Hay que obtener la comida correcta del array
    let meal = ClaseStaticGuardar.meals[indexPath.row]

    // Establecer los datos a mostrar en la vista
    cell.nameLabel.text = meal.name
    cell.photoImageView.image = meal.photo
    cell.ratingControl.rating = meal.rating

    return cell
}


// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}



// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        ClaseStaticGuardar.meals.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        saveMeals()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/


// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {

    case "AddItem":
        os_log("Adding a new meal.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)

    case "ShowDetail":
        guard let tabBarController = segue.destination as? UITabBarController else {
            fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
        }

//            guard let mealDetailViewController = tabBarController.viewControllers?.first as? NameMealViewController else {
//                fatalError("Couldn't instantiate NameMealViewController from tabbar")
//            }

        guard let selectedMealCell = sender as? MealTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(String(describing: sender))")
        }

        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedMealCell) else {
            fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
        }

        let selectedMeal = ClaseStaticGuardar.meals[indexPath.row]
        for i in (tabBarController.viewControllers)!{
            let nombre = i as? NameMealViewController

            nombre?.meal = selectedMeal
        }

 //            mealDetailViewController.meal = selectedMeal

    default:
        fatalError("Unexpected Segue Identifier; \(String(describing: segue.identifier))")
    }
}


// MARK: Actions
@IBAction func unwindToMealList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? MealViewController, let meal = sourceViewController.meal {

        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            // Update an existing meal.
            ClaseStaticGuardar.meals[selectedIndexPath.row] = meal
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
        }
        else {



            // Add a new meal.
            let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 
    ClaseStaticGuardar.meals.count, section: 0)

            ClaseStaticGuardar.meals.append(meal)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
        // Save the meals.
        saveMeals()
    }
}

// MARK: Private methods
private func loadSampleMeals() {
    // Cargar las imágenes de prueba
    let photo1 = UIImage(named: "meal1")
    let photo2 = UIImage(named: "meal2")
    let photo3 = UIImage(named: "meal3")

guard let meal1 = Meal(name: "Ensalada Caprese", photo: photo1, rating: 4, index: 0) else {
        fatalError("No se puede instanciar meal1")
    }

    guard let meal2 = Meal(name: "Pollo con patatas", photo: photo2, rating: 5, index: 1) else {
        fatalError("No se puede instanciar meal2")
    }

    guard let meal3 = Meal(name: "Pasta con albóndigas", photo: photo3, rating: 3, index: 2) else {
        fatalError("No se puede instanciar meal3")
    }

    // Una vez creadas correctamente, se insertan en el array
    ClaseStaticGuardar.meals += [meal1, meal2, meal3]

}



private func saveMeals() {
    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(ClaseStaticGuardar.meals, toFile: Meal.ArchiveURL.path)
    if isSuccessfulSave {
        os_log("Meals successfully saved.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
    } else {
        os_log("Failed to save meals...", log: OSLog.default, type: .error)
    }
}


private func loadMeals() -> [Meal]?  {
    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: Meal.ArchiveURL.path) as? [Meal]
}

}
```

Entonces de esta manera cada vez que actualices un nuevo Meal actualizalo local o en la variable nuevoMeal o podrias usar otro arreglo de meals static que guarde cambios y luego reemplazarlo por el principal, son varias opciones.

En tu clase tabbarViewController por ejemplo puedes hacer na función para guardar, y desde ahí validar o actualizar los valores del arreglo de meals.

```
    @IBAction func SaveTap(_ sender: Any) {

    ClaseStaticGuardar.meals.remove(at: (ClaseStaticGuardar.nuevoMeal?.index)!)
    ClaseStaticGuardar.meals.insert(ClaseStaticGuardar.nuevoMeal!, at: (ClaseStaticGuardar.nuevoMeal?.index)!)
}
```

Es solo un par de ideas que te pueden ayudar, necesitas obvio agregar validaciones o darle la lógica de modificar o guardar que quieras, lo importante de lo que te explique es que veas que puedes ir guardando los estados de las variables en la ClaseStatic y utilizarlos en cualquier parte de tu código.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola!! Primero, darte las gracias por tu respuesta. Tengo un problema con el método `init` de la clase Meal. Me aparece el siguiente error: Property 'self.index' not initialized at implicitly generated super.init call ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? Me puedes poner cómo quedaría la clase Meal para saber en qué me estoy equivocando? Acabo de resubir el repositorio con los cambios que me propones para que puedas ver el error. Muchas gracias por todo, espero que podamos solucionar este error.

Comment: Eso es por que  var index: Int al declarar se deja de esta manera y por consiguiente swift piensa que es con !, osea que es obligatorio, las variables obligatorias deben ser siempre inicializadas, entonces tienes dos opciones:
1.- declarar de esta manera var index: Int?
a si con al simbolo estas diciendo que esa variable podria ir nil, pero no es verdad, el index SIEMPRE le debes dar un valor.

Comment: Opcion 2.- var index: Int = 0 , o en el init hacer una delcaración directa con index = 0,
Opcion 3.- 
    init?(name: String, photo: UIImage?, rating: Int, index: Int) {
        
        // Si el nombre o la valoración no son válidos, devuelvo nulo
        if (name.isEmpty || rating < 0 || rating > 5) {
            return nil
        }
        
        self.name = name
        self.photo = photo
        self.rating = rating
        self.index = index
    }

Comment: tendrias que corregir las llamadas de los init por que te empezara a marcar errores de que te falta enviar el valor del index, recuerda para el index tu deberia controlarlo cada vez que envies un valor le envias el index, puedes hacer un calculo para obtener el ultimo valor index del array y sumrle uno para el nuevo etc..

Comment: y no te pierdas con el index, recuerda al agregar uno nuevo, 
var indexTmp = ClassStaticSave.meals.last?.index + 1
no recuerdo si es con last con el que obtienes el ultimo valor del array, pero seria algo a si la idea para ir incrementando el index al enviar el nuevo index en cada elemento

Comment: var indexTmp = (ClassStaticSave.meals.last?.index)! + 1
 Meal(name: name, photo: photo, rating: rating, index: indexTmp)
Algo a si serialo que te faltaria, obvio tienes que validar que cuando el array este nil o vacio le envies el primer valor como 0, o 1 directamente sin hacer la suma

Comment: No consigo solucionar este error. He hecho los cambios y no se soluciona... ¿Podrías poner una nueva respuesta con el código de cómo se quedaría?

Comment: El error sale por que no has inicializado index, solo inicializalo. index = 0, o index = -1 dependendiendo la logica que vayas a usar para irlo incrementando, y para inicializalo es dentro del init, o en la declaracion de la variable